# Laravel get sections data as an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Assume I have a view file `view/admin/users.blade.php` with this content:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('head')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />
@endsection
@section('content')
  <div class="row">
     <table>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>email</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
         <tr>
           <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
           <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
         </tr>
        @endforeach
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
  <script src="/js/script1.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/script2.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Is there any method to get the sections(with each sections data) as an array? Like so :

```
[
  'head'    => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style1.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style2.css" />',
  'content' => '<div class="row"><table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>email</th></tr></thead><tbody>@foreach($users as $user)<tr><td>{{ $user->id }}</td><td>{{ $user->email }}</td></tr>@endforeach</tbody></table></div>',
  'scripts' => '<script src="/js/script1.js"></script><script src="/js/script2.js"></script>'
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `renderSections` method.

```
$view = view('blade.template')->with(compact('something'));
dd($view->renderSections());
```

which returns assoc array keyed by its section name.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Can I do some stuff on each array data and revert it back and render all of them ?

Comment: Revert it back? I'm not sure on what you meant, but you can instantiate another view factory instance. `$view = view('blade.template')->renderSections(); return view('blade.template);`